# CDI Instances not found in JAR inside WEB-INF/lib

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, ejb, cdi

I have a maven JSF project with several modules which is deployed to Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

Structure of the resulting EAR:

```
|-- lib
|-- META-INF
|-- core-module.jar (packaged as ejbModule by maven)
|   |-- com
|   |   |-- ApplicationSettings.java
|   |   |-- Module.java (Module interface)
|   |   `-- ModuleCORE.java (implementation of Module interface)
|   `-- META-INF
|       `-- beans.xml
`-- presentation-module.war (packaged as warModule by maven)
    |-- WEB-INF
    |   |-- beans.xml
    |   `-- lib
    |       |-- jar-module.jar
    |       |   |-- com
    |       |   |   `-- ModuleEXT1.java (implementation of Module interface)
    |       |   `-- META-INF
    |       |       `-- beans.xml
    |       `-- another-jar-module.jar
    |           |-- com
    |           |   `-- ModuleEXT2.java (implementation of Module interface)
    |           `-- META-INF
    |               `-- beans.xml
    |-- images
    |-- css
    |-- js
    `-- listModules.xhtml
```

I have three modules:

- core-module
- ext1-module
- ext2-module

The following interface exists in the EJB-Module:

```
//Module.java
public interface Module {
    public String getName();
}
```

Each module itself implements the interface and returns their name:

- ModuleCORE.java
- ModuleEXT1.java
- ModuleEXT2.java

In the core-module there is the following bean that `listModules.xhtml` refers to in order to display the list of modules:

```
//ApplicationSettings.java
@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class ApplicationSettings {
    @Inject
    @Any
    private Instance<Module> modules;

    public List<String> getModuleList() {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Module module : modules) {
            result.add(module.getName());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that only the implementation of the core-Module is in the list of Instances. The implementations of the modules inside `WEB-INF/lib` are not found although the respective `META-INF/beans.xml` exist.

Can someone explain to me why CDI cannot find all instances of the `Module` interface?

Sidenote: Other `@Named` beans from the JAR inside `WEB-INF/lib` are injectable/can be used in the xhtml files. So basically CDI is doing its job and thus is inspecting the directories.

Comment: What version of CDI are you using and which container?

Comment: @Templar I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Weld 1.1.4.Final. Check this link: https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2.2-final.html

Comment: As per Java EE spec, classes in EJB module can't see classes in WAR module. So, it's end of story.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for the information. Can you think of anything to work around this? - Basically I want to dynamically extend my project with JAR's including classes/resources/xhtml but also recognize my extensions. As far as I know the only way to use JAR's in that manner is to place them in `WEB-INF/lib` and manage the resources under `META-INF/resources` inside the JAR so that the container finds them (the resources etc.). But there is still the issue on how to recognize which extension is currently present...

Comment: Have you tried placing the extensions in EAR/lib? This location is visible both from the WAR *and* the EJB-JAR.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, using EARs with CDI has been considered tricky at best, fruitless at worse.  If you don't have a hard requirement to use an EAR, if you can put `core-module` into your `WEB-INF/lib` you'll end up with the results you expect.

Comment: That's right, but unfortunately I have two other WAR's aside `presentation-module` (two webservices in this case) that require `core-module` as well. In this case I would have to copy it into each `WEB-INF/lib` which wouldn't be that nice.

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't be nice.  Another thing you can try is to use a portable extension to install `ApplicationSettings` and `ModuleCORE` into the WAR file's context.